# Finite Taylor series of Lagrange Basis functions

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, lagrange-interpolation

Lagrange basis functions are defined as follows $$L_{j}(x) = \prod_{i\neq j} \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}} $$

then $$\ln\Big(L_{j}(x)\Big) = \ln\Big(\prod_{i\neq j} \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}}  \Big) = \sum_{i \neq j } \ln\Big( \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}} \Big) $$

if we derivate we have:

$$ \frac{L'_{j}(x)}{L_{j}(x)} =\sum_{i \neq j} \frac{\frac{1}{x_{j}-x_{i}}}{\frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}}} = \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  $$ 
then

$$ L_{j}^{(1)}(x) = L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)  $$

if we use the product rule for  derivatives we have that:

$$ L''_{j}(x) = L'_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)+L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)' \\ = 
 L'_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)+L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{-1}{(x-x_{i})^2}  \Big) $$ we know $ L'_{j}(x)  $  so $$ \\ = 
 L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)\Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)-L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^2}  \Big)\\ = 
L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)^2 -L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^2}  \Big) $$ finally $$  L_{j}^{(2)}(x) = 
L_{j}(x) \Big\{\Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)^2 -  \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^2}     \Big\} $$

if we continue this way we get:

$$ L_{j}^{(3)}(x) =  L_{j}(x)\Big\{ \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)^3 -3 \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^2}  \Big) +2\Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^3}  \Big)  \Big\} $$

I want to compute the Taylor Series of $ L_{j}(x) $ and I need to find  $ L_{j}^{(n)}(x) $ .  Do you know an expression for $ L_{j}^{(n)}(x) $ or something that could help ? Thank you.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Derivatives

Comment: yeah, I saw that but I would like to know where that formulas come from...

Comment: I think I'm missing something, is there a theorem that tell me that? (what is the theorem's name?) because I still dont get it. ...do you know a book that can help?

Comment: Taylor series of a polynomial is the polynomial itself because the derivatives are eventually zero. Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19x213y_uk4

Comment: Let me see if I understand, the answer below is the sketch of the proof that $ T_{a}[L_{j}](x) = L_{j}(x) $ ?

Comment: In the answer  I use that equality to compute the coefficients of the expansion.

Comment: I revised my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: I have questions:  1. $a_{k} $ is always a constant?   , 2.  instead of derivating $ \prod{ \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}} } $ we derivate $\sum{ b_{i}(x-x_{0})^{i} }$ ?

Comment: 1. Given $L_j$, the coefficents $a_k$ are constant. The question 2. is not clear. I do not derivate.

Answer (score 1):

Since $L_j$ is a polynomial, in order to compute the Taylor series, you don't need to compute the derivatives: Taylor series of a polynomial is the polynomial itself because the derivatives are eventually zero.

If $L_{j}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ then, by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas), the coefficient of $x^k$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$ is
$$a_k:=[x^k]L_{j}(x) = [x^k]\prod_{i\neq j} \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1-k} \sum_{|I|=n-1-k}\prod_{i\in I}x_{i}}{\prod_{i\neq j} (x_{j}-x_{i})}$$
where the sum is taken over all subsets $I$ of $\{1,2,\dots,j-1,j+1,\dots,n\}$ of cardinality $n-1-k$.
Hence the Taylor expansion of $L_j$ at $0$ is
$$L_j(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k.$$
If you need the Taylor expansion at $x_0$ then consider
$$\begin{align}L_j(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k((x-x_0+x_0)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}x_0^{k-i}(x-x_0)^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_i(x-x_0)^i
\end{align}$$
where
$\displaystyle b_i=\sum_{k=i}^{n-1}a_k\binom{k}{i}x_0^{k-i}.$

For example, if $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$ and $x_3=3$, then the Taylor expansion of $L_2$ at $-2$ is
$$L_2(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-3)}{(2-1)(2-3)}=
-15+8(x+2)-(x+2)^2$$
where $a_0=-3$, $a_1=4$, $a_2=-1$, and
$$\begin{align}
b_2&=\sum_{k=2}^{3-1}a_k\binom{k}{2}(-2)^{k-2}=a_2=-1,\\
b_1&=\sum_{k=1}^{3-1}a_k\binom{k}{1}(-2)^{k-1}=a_1-4a_2=4-4\cdot (-1)=8,\\
b_0&=\sum_{k=0}^{3-1}a_k\binom{k}{0}(-2)^{k-0}=a_0-2a_1+4a_2=-3-2\cdot 4+4\cdot (-1)=-15.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I love this example...but could you show how you computed $a_{k}$?  because I do not understand the last expression for $a_{k}$

Comment: Just expand the polynomial $L_2$: $\frac{(x-1)(x-3)}{(2-1)(2-3)}=(x^2-4x+3)/(-1)=-3+4x-x^2$.

Comment: ok, but to compute $a_{k}$ do  we always have to expand the polynomial?

Comment: Yes, this is the same of using the Vieta's formulas.

Comment: nice!...I didn't know about that!  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's Theorem says that if $f$ has derivatives $f^{(1)},f^{(2)},...,f^{(n)},f^{(n+1)}$ defined on an interval $[a,x]$ then

$$f(x) - T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\lambda)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)}$$

for some $\lambda \in (a,x)$ and where

$$T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} { \frac{f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k}{k!} } $$

if we take $f(x) =  a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}\ \ $
a polynomial of degree $n$... note that $f^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$. 
For example $h(x)=x^2$ has derivatives $h^{(1)}(x)=2x$, $h^{(2)}(x)=2$
and finally $h^{(3)}(x) =0$

Then

$$f(x) - T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\lambda)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)} = \frac{0}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{(n+1)} = 0$$ and this implies that

$$ T_{a}^{n}\{f\}(x) = f(x) =  a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0} $$

Thus the Taylor Series of a polynomial is the polynomial. This is just a particular case.